# Multiple copies of the same SVG displayed with errors on Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, fill, display, linear-gradients

I have an array of svg objects that I need to use. Each svg is inserted at two different sections of the HTML when the page is loaded and only one section is displayed at a given time. I use the display property and media queries to hide/unhide the complete section containing the SVGs and other tags.

Each SVG have at least two parts (A/B); part A is a single color but part B use a LinearGradient for Fill.

This method works fine in Chrome, and IE explorer but Firefox does not display part B of the SVG when the media query is called.

I tried changing the id of the linearGradient url to a class, removed the  tags, use the  and  tags, changed the display property types, but nothing worked.

This is simplyfied version of the problem:

https://codepen.io/eddieWin/pen/JOoMLe

Thanks for any help you can give me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        #one{
            display: block;
        }
        #two{
            display: none;
        }

        .svgIcon{
            display: inline-block;
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
        #container{
            display: flex;
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 568px) {

            #one{
                display: none;
            }
            #two{
                display: block;
            }

        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<section id="one">
    <h1>One</h1>
    <div class="svgContainer"></div>
</section>

<section id="two">
    <div id="container">
        <div>
            <div class="svgContainer"></div>
        </div>
        <h1>Two</h1>
    </div>
</section>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var svgIcons = {
        'svg1' : '\
        <div class="svgIcon">\
            <svg version="1.1" class="infoIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"\
                 width="72px" height="70px" viewBox="0 0 72 70">\
                <defs>\
                    <linearGradient id="info_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="32.895" y1="49.7476" x2="32.895" y2="28.2964">\
                        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#ff88ff"/>\
                        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#88dddd"/>\
                    </linearGradient>\
                </defs>\
                <circle cx="35" cy="35" r="30" fill="#555555"/>\
                <circle cx="35" cy="35" r="20" fill="url(#info_1_)"/>\
            </svg>\
        </div>'
    }

    var svgContainers = document.getElementsByClassName('svgContainer');

    for(var i = 0; i < svgContainers.length; i++){
        svgContainers[i].innerHTML = svgIcons['svg1'];
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Having more than one element with the same id is not allowed. You seem to be creating > 1 element with the id="info_1_"

Comment: Thank you for your reply Robert. I tried to reference the linearGradient with a class name instead but that didn't work. However your post got me thinking in another way to solve the problem. I updated the code pen with the fix. I defined the svg in the html and hide it, then I just call the svg when I need it with <use xlink:href="iconName">